# How to override PrimeFaces CSS via external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, el

I have the following code on my xhtml page to override default PrimeFaces styling:

```
<h:body>
  <f:facet name="last">
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" />
  </f:facet>
  ...
</h:body>
```

This works fine when I am using a stylesheet, that is stored locally on my server.
The Problem is, that I want to include a external (dynamic) stylesheet. So when I am changing the `<h:facet>` to something like the following, it doesn't work anymore.

```
  <f:facet name="last">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://host.de/main.css" />
  </f:facet>
```

If I include the `<link>` element directly into the `<h:head>` section of my xhtml page the stylesheet is loaded but the rules get overridden by PrimeFaces.

In the next step I would like to set the `href` attribute dynamic from my `ManagedBean` to something like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{bean.cssUrl}" />
```

Is this even possible? Or is there another way to achieve what I am describing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome (each latest version) and none is working. If I use `<h:outputStylesheet name="http://host.de/test.css">` instead of `<link>` I get `RES_NOT_FOUND` and status code 404.

Comment: About the last question, it's entirely possible, sure. Don't know why it doesn't work in the second code snippet, the load order should be maintained despite of the resource being alocated in other host. Have you tried it with different browsers and forcing cache reloading?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks for your tip. I tried with different browsers, but same result.

Comment: Hey where do u store ur css files in webapp i mean folder and have u tried <h:outputStylesheet name="http://host.de/test.css" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<facet name="last"/>` for stylesheets  should only be used in `<h:head/>` that is where your stylesheets should end up anyway. If you load them last in your body, you can get weird manifestations in the look and feel of your ui. While loading and building the page and having some slower connections or a busy server, the PF stylesheet is used and when finished loading, your custom css kicks in. This might cause reflows, color changes abd what more

Comment: `<f:facet name="last">` worked perfectly using it in `<h:body>`. Problems began when using `<link>` instead of `<h:outputStylesheet>`.

Comment: You were right. I didn't understand at first. A colleague of mine used `<f:facet name="last">` in `<h:body>` and I adopted it wrong. Thank you a lot :)`

Comment: For scripts it has some value (unless the scripts influence the L&F to)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The solution was to remove the surrounding `<f:facet>` element and directly put the `<link>` under `<h:body>`:

```
<h:body>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{bean.cssUri}"></link>
  ...
</h:body>
```

With this solution I am also able to set the URL of the external stylesheet dynamically in the `@PostConstruct` method of my `ManagedBean` (scope is `@ViewScoped`).

**EDIT:**

It may be working but @Kukeltje's answer is cleaner and more accurate. I was using `<f:facet name="last">` wrong.

Updated code snippet:

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{bean.cssUri}"></link>
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

Comment: Sorry, wanted to remove my downvote and it got locked. Why do you load the css in `h:body` and not `h:head`

Comment: I have to make sure that my stlyesheet gets loaded last because I am overriding PrimeFaces css classes.

Comment: Then it still can and should end up in `h:head`. If you load it last in body you can, on slower connections, get ui's that suddenly change appearance since while loading and building thr page it uses PF stylesheets and at the end your stylesheet suddenly kiks in, causing e.g. reflows, color changes and more